# Import OpenCV for Blackberry 10

Tags: opencv, blackberry-10, augmented-reality, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx

I want to include OpenCV library into my cascades project but I don't know how to do it because of luck of documentation.. Please I need help!
PS : I'm using Windows 7 64bits.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't built it for BB10, I have built OpenCV for a number of other platforms.  Here's what I would do:

1. Look for someone else's prebuilt binaries. For example http://www.greenviolet.net/~lewellyn/OpenCV-QNX.zip
2. If you need to build it yourself, simply create a library project for each sub-library of OpenCV in Momentics and add the source code to it with reference to the CMake lists files (to make sure the right source code ends up in the right library).  I would suggest not wasting time trying to get a working build off the command line or looking for direct support for OpenCV on BB10.  If you take this approach, what will build easily is cv, cvaux, cxcore, etc..  highgui will not build this way since it is based on camera capture and gui for desktop platforms.
3. If you need camera support, go low-level with the BB10 capture API.  You can construct cv::Mat objects around an existing pointer to RGB24 data easily.  I can't recall if the frames are in NV21 (aka YUV semi-planar) or RGB24 format, but in any case there may now be NV21 support in OpenCV.  If not, there is conversion code out there to do the conversion in software. http://labs.movenda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/arm_yuv2rgb.zip

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for importing Open Source libraries is contained on this page: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/library_support_at_a_glance.html

You will find a BlackBerry GitHUB link for OpenCV there. I don't know how much work has been done as far as porting goes.